# ASP.net MVC 3 Type or Namespace error 'DocApprove'

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to build my application but I keep getting an error. This is what is presented:

The type or namespace name 'DocApprove' does not exist in the namespace 'EngineeringPortalMVC.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I'm not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you have the following reference:

```
EngineeringPortalMVC.Models.DocApprove
```

and that model/namespace does not exist or is not in the specified namespace. You need to do a solution wide search for EngineeringPortalMVC.Models.DocApprove and fix the issue by referencing the appropriate namespace where DocApprove is actually located.